# Session variables not being transported

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables, authentication

I'm learnig PHP (as a hobby) and I wanted to build a simple login page to practice.

I have a form:

```
<form action="phpAction/checklogin.php" method="POST">
<p>Username:</p>
<input type="text" name="username">
<p>Password:</p>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br><br>
<a href="signup.php">You don't have an account yet?</a>
</form>
```

Posting to the php code:

```
<?php

// Starts a MySQLi connection to the database
include "../includes/mysqliConn.php";

// Starts a session to keep the user logged in
session_start();

// Posts the username and password from the form and stores it into a session variable

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
  $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
  $_SESSION["password"] = $_POST["password"];
} else {
    die("You cannot be here!");
}
// Checks login
$checklogin = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $_SESSION["username"] AND password = $_SESSION["password"]';
$result = $conn->query($checklogin);
                if ($result->num_rows = 0){
                    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login and/or password wrong!');window.location.href='login.php';</script>";
                    die();
                } else {
                    // Variable to other pages see that the user is logged in
                    $_SESSION["islogged"] = "true";
                    // Redirects to the homepage
                    header("Location: ../index.php");
                }

?>
```

It sets the session variable "islogged" to true so that other pages can diplay user's information.

In the header of the website I have this:

```
<?php

      if ($_SESSION["islogged"] == "true") {
          echo "<a href='#'>Panel</a>";
          echo "<a href='#'>Logout</a>";
      } else {
         echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
         echo "<a href='#'> / </a>";
         echo "<a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a>"; 
      }

?>
```

When the variable "islogged" is set to "true", the page should display the links Panel and Logout, instead of the Login and Signup ones. But I keep getting the login and signup.
It seems like the session variables are not being "transported".

Any kind of help is appreciated.

PS: Sorry for bad English :P

Thanks

Comment: 1. you can't put any variables *(`$_SESSION["username"]`)* inside single quotes it must be double quotes.  2.  You should look at SQL injection prevention and prepared statements with PDO/Mysqli

Comment: i'm using single quotes because if I put double quotes I get an 500 Error

Comment: Are you invoke `session_start` before checking `$_SESSION["islogged"]` in other pages?

Comment: @João yah `= 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $_SESSION["username"]`  Does not work because of single quotes... use double quotes.

Comment: did you echo the S_SESSION["username"] before if statement just check its value and let us know.

Comment: oh, thank you. but now I get "Wrong password or username" even though they are correct in the database...

Comment: Please elaborate more on your problem 1. Which one of the two files come first in code the first one or header one  2. What did you get the  value of S_SESSION["username"] before if statement in header file 3.Did you encode you password or storing it as a plain text (bad practice). I suggest an edit to your question.

Comment: @geeksal i have an index page which is including the header and the mysql connection page. I'm not echo'ing any session variables.

Comment: @ash how can I use double quotes is I have other double quotes in the variables?

Comment: @João use single quotes in your variables? `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: @João I told you to echo it and let me know the value. I can't do it because I don't have your database, so it is very difficult to know what went wrong.

Comment: @geeksal it displays a white screen, i can't do double quotes inside double quotes, and i can't do single quotes because it needs double quotes to call the variable :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know anything other then numbers must be enclosed in a `' '` . Just try this one

```
 $checklogin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND password ='".$_SESSION['password']."'";
```

I hope this works.

Comment: @João welcome! don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To use `$_SESSION` variables, run `session_start()` first. The example that you have marked as "in the header of the web site," you're not running `session_start()` first.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

> session_start() creates a session **or resumes the current one** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.